Wrong SSL certificate but for only one computer
The SSL certificate for one website that I manage seems to be fine, however, I am receiving an error for that site on a single computer. The error says that the certificate expired 22 days ago, but again, the cert is working fine on every other computer.
So, I am assuming it's just my computer. I have tried clearing the cache, but it didn't help.
Anyone have any ideas?
I have tried clearing the cache, but it didn't help.

Server certificates are not cached, but are retrieved again with each TLS handshake.  Maybe this single system is using a different IP address to access the server than the others, for example old DNS entry, local host file, IPv4 vs. IPv6, ... . Check also your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Maybe a dumb question: But did you check if the local machine has the correct date and time set? Can you inspect the certificate on this particular machine and check if the correct certificate is used? If you receive a different certificate than you expect, your machine is connecting to a different remote site ...

Thanks, @SteffenUllrich I found that in my local host file, the site had an IP address not associated with it. I'm not sure why or how that happened, as I didn't make that change.
